# Can I use code to control the dependency resolution decisions made by ApplicationContext in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am using auto wiring in Spring Boot to inject implementations of interfaces into classes that are marked as component.
Sometimes I need to run the application (and or tests) with particular implementations of some of the interfaces.
I am aware that this can be done with combinations of annotations (`@Qualifier`, `@Primary` and more) but these are not suitable for my needs.
I would like to be able to (optionally) write code that runs before the `ApplicationContext` determine which implementations of my interfaces will be created and in that code to override one or more of those decisions.

I have tried to use code like this:

```
context.registerBean(MyService.class, () -> new MyService());
```

as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans.

But I could not find the place in code to insert this early enough so that it would effect all autowired fields in the application.
In particular this is a problem in tests (marked `@SpringBootTest`).

I would like to be able to use code that looks similar to how it is done in C#:

In one test I might use this code and then run the test:

```
container.Register<IDataLayer, MockDataLayer>();
container.Register<IPersistenceLayer, FilePersistenceLayer>();
```

In another test I might use this code and then run the test:

```
container.Register<IDataLayer, SQLDataLayer>();
container.Register<IPersistenceLayer, MockPersistenceLayer>();
```

And in production I might run this

```
container.Register<IDataLayer, SQLDataLayer>();
container.Register<IPersistenceLayer, FilePersistenceLayer>();
```

or simply rely on file configuration.

Is it possible to create this level of control over the choices made by `ApplicationContext` or must I rely on brittle choices of annotations and xml configuration files to make each of my tests to run exactly as I need?

Comment: is there some problem using code-based configuration files for this? (xml configuration is generally not preferred anymore)

Comment: I prefer not to have to use configuration files at all. I would like to control it in code. That gives me better control and is more maintainable in a development environment.
I am not familiar with the combination "code-based" together with "configuration files". 
Can you provide a link to this kind of solution so that I can take a look?

Comment: java code-based configuration are code, and are standard way of doing Spring configurations. [here's one example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-configuration-annotation/). Generally configuration files themselves are scanned by Spring, but if you want to do that also manually, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) shows an example.

Comment: If I understand, you need dynamic annotation for choosing the implementation class.

Comment: @eis Thank you for this pointer. If this works, it does look like what I need, but I see that though it is invoked for some of my autowired fields it is not invoked for others. 
For instance, it seems that one of my implementations hitherto annotated as Primary is still created.
I have a standard spring boot application with most of my classes in main/java and some tests and test classes in test/java.
How should I use this Configuration pattern to make sure that it will control all resolution choices?
Should it be sufficient to remove all Primary annotations to achieve this?

Comment: @DavidSackstein without seeing your code it is hard to tell what is the problem and what you need to change, but if only some of your autowired fields are populated but not others, it is a singal that those others are not part of spring lifecycle (=have not been configured to be picked up by spring), and those that are created have been registered in Spring lifecycle, one way or other.

Comment: @eis When I removed the Primary annotation from one of the two implementations, Spring failed to load because it has three possible ways to create the bean: the two implementations and the factory method in the Configuration class. Do you now how I can force Spring to always use the configuration class whenever it has an appropriate factory method for a bean?

Comment: @DavidSackstein how or where are the two implementations registered to spring lifecycle?

Comment: @eis The two implementations are marked as Component.
One is located under the main/java and the other (mock) is under test/java.
Until now, I have done the following.
I annotate the one in the test as Primary.
This way, for production, Spring only sees the one in main, and for tests Spring sees both but takes the mock because it is the primary.
This works, but it is not very flexible because it doesn't allow me to programmatically decide in some of the tests to selectively use the implementation that is in main/java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional beans is a new feature of Spring 5 which is more geared to registration of functions as bean providers. If all you need is code-based configuration, you don't need to go there but can use standard Spring annotation-based configuration.

### Regular, standard Spring javaconfig

Trivial example, configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DemoManager helloWorld()
    {
        return new DemoManagerImpl();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This will use component scanning to find your configuration class, and then call its methods to get the beans. You can provide configuration classes you want as arguments, and SpringBootTest you mentioned also supports that.

So when testing, you could use your own test configuration then to customize which beans get loaded and to provide additional beans. If the configuration class is a nested class, you don't need to specify it even:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SpringBootDemoApplicationTests
{  
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
       // ...
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyTestConfiguration {

        //tests specific beans
        @Bean
        DataSource createDataSource(){
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Using `@TestConfiguration` will add to your configuration - if you don't want to add but rather replace configuration altogether, use `@SpringBootTest(classes = YourCustomConfiguration.class)`.

### Alternative: manually created app context, with spring javaconfig

If you don't want to use javaconfig or component scanning but instead want to also register your configuration classes "yourself", you can do it for example like having this kind of main method in main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

   HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
   helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
   helloWorld.getMessage();
}
```

it is not generally used, but it's not wrong either.

### Alternative 2: manual app context, manual bean registrations

If you really want to avoid also the configuration class, you can also do it like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class SomeClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    // first, we create empty context ourselves
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    // then we get its bean factory to be able to register stuff
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ctx.getBeanFactory();

    // register our bean
    YourBean beanToRegister = new YourBean();
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanToRegister.getClass().getCanonicalName(), beanToRegister);

    ctx.refresh(); // context refresh actually updates the status

    // here we can test a bean was actually created and working
    YourBean helloWorld = ctx.getBean(YourBean.class);
    helloWorld.setAuthor("Hello World!");
    System.out.println(helloWorld.getAuthor());
  }
}
```

like the other alternative, this is not a common approach with Spring, but it's not wrong either.

Comment: I think the "Regular, standard Spring javaconfig" will be a good solution for me, but I have a question.
When I use this method should I remove the Component annotation from the classes so that resolution through the Configuration class is unambiguous?

Comment: @DavidSackstein yes, for the beans you configure using javaconfig configuration. You can mix the approaches but don't do it for the same classes, and I would prefer using just one or the other for the entire application. `@Component` is about component scan autoconfiguration, and javaconfig is where you do the declarations yourself - you shouldn't have both for the same classes. (you *can* have, but then you declare the same bean twice with different definitions, unless the name is identical in which case the definitions will override each other, which is also not optimal).

Comment: Great. This seems to work. I have a few more questions about this.
If I create a nested class annotated with Configuration in one SpringBootTest annotated class and another class annotated with Configuration in another SpringBootTest annotated class with each test run with its own configuration, or will these two conflict. If they will not conflict is it in fact because the classes are nested? because they are not visible?  If they were public in each test class would they conflict?

Comment: @DavidSackstein there is potential for conflict. Specific behaviour is a bit version dependent in Spring. If I recall correctly, in general a visible `@Configuration` class will conflict with others (as it is eligible for component scanning), but visible `@TestConfiguration` class will not (and will need importing explicitly). Spring documentation [recommends](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-excluding-config) using @Import and @TestConfiguration if there is potential for conflict.

Comment: (ps. if you feel my answer has helped solving this specific question, consider upvoting and/or accepting it. for more questions, opening a new question could be in order.)

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I have verified that "Regular, standard Spring javaconfig" works for me.
The use of static for the nested class is important. Without it, the class was ignored by Spring. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you are looking for something which run on specific implementation on specific requirement.
Please look into this class:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean

You can configure it and define the implementations and get the bean as per the requirement.

```
<beans:bean id="dataStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="com.abc.DataStrategyFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:alias name="FileImpl" alias="FILE" />
    <beans:alias name="DBImpl" alias="DB" />
    <beans:alias name="WSImpl" alias="WS" />
    <beans:alias name="NativeImpl" alias="DEFAULT" />
```

Provide the interface implementation(here, DataStrategyFactory) and get the object at the runtime on requirement.

Comment: I prefer not to use the Service Locator pattern because it couples my code to Spring and because it gives classes the ability to abuse the SL and request anything they like. Dependency injection can also be abused by classes, but it relies (especially constructor injection) on dependencies being declared explicitly on the class.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly you only need conditional beans for your tests, I suggest you declare your "production" `@Bean`s on your main classes and then for your tests you can use the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` with a `@TestConfiguration` overriding the beans you need.

Something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties={"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
public class MyConditionalTest {

    @Test
    public void testMyStuff() { 
    // do your test here
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public OverrideSpringBean {

       @Bean
       public IDataLayer dataLayer() {
           return new MockPersistenceLayer();
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that this is indeed the right direction for me, but I have another question on this approach.
This is still rigid in the sense that each Test in MyConditionalTest will use the same implementations of these beans. Can I extend this approach so that different tests may run with different implementations of the interfaces?
If I can create different test classes each with their own nested OverrideSpringBean each resolving to different beans, then that might be a complete solution. But I am concerned that with two nested configuration classes will conflict.

Comment: You can create multiple TestConfiguration classes containing your test beans and then on each of your test classes you import it as you need, something like `@Import(TestConfig.class)`, it might solve your problem. Or if you use nested classes to override your Beans (as on my example) it also works, the `bean`s definitions aren't shared between test classes.

Comment: If I use the first approach - multiple TestConfiguration classes. Will they not conflict with eachother? If they are not nested and therefore not scoped in some way, how does Spring decide which one to use? Is the Import annotation what makes this work? Is it true that without explicit Import none of the TestConfiguration class will be selected for use?

Comment: If it’s inside the same package being scanned from the main app it might be a problem. You can create an package outside of the auto scan and then import it independently

Comment: I see. OK. I will try the nested class approach.

Comment: I tried this code but it didnt work. That is:
I my interface is not a Component. Neither are the two implementations.
Instead there is one ProductConfiguration class annotated as Configuration that returns one implementation and in the test I have a nested class. The test class and configuration class are annotated as you show above.
The result is that when I run the test in this test class, the factory method in the configuration class from main/java is invoked. The one in the nested class is ignored.
Is there any other configuration I need to do?

Comment: You could try profiles but I don’t believe it’s necessary. I’ll try to build an example here and share on GitHub for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201474/discussion-between-david-sackstein-and-marcos-barbero).